# How to use windows 7 terminal services to create the additional session

Tags: windows-7, terminal-services

I using two monitors on the same computer, I want to create an additional session to use on the second monitor. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you graphics board can already handle two displays, then why not just localize them to the current machine?  The responsiveness will be higher as well as the usefullness of this move. I am doing this now using my NVIDIA graphics card.

Comment: Because I want to share my computer for two people using at the same time. (two monitors, two keyboards and two mouses)

Comment: I don't see how you are going to share/split additional keyboards or mice operations one one platform between two users.

Comment: miniframe can do that, and it is using terminal services to create an additional session

Comment: Then miniframe apparently is your solution.

Comment: At first, I want to know how to create another session using terminal services and you driving it into a different direction.

Comment: I'm trying to explore other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 natively does not support more than one user connected with Remote Desktop or Remote Desktop + Local user. These features are reserved for Windows Servers for obvious reasons.
However, if you search a bit there are modified versions of termsrv.dll(plus some reg changes) that allow you to have multiple RDP sessions.